# Clickbank INS V6.0 Integration c#

Tags: clickbank

I am trying to integrate CLickBankINSV6.0 to my c# application.

I have tried by using a sample response like:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "version": 6,
        "attemptCount": 0,
        "role": "VENDOR",
        "site": "nicholeen",
        "receipt": "********",
        "currency": "USD",
        "transactionType": "TEST",
        "transactionTime": 1406070122781,
        "paymentMethod": "VISA",
        "totalProductAmount": 1,
        "totalTaxAmount": 0,
        "totalShippingAmount": 0,
        "customer": {
            "shipping": {
                "firstName": "TEST",
                "lastName": "USER",
                "fullName": "Test User",
                "email": "testuser@somesite.com",
                "address": {}
            },
            "billing": {
                "firstName": "TEST",
                "lastName": "USER",
                "fullName": "Test User",
                "email": "testuser@somesite.com",
                "address": {}
            }
        },
        "lineItems": [
            {
                "itemNo": "1",
                "productTitle": "A passed in title",
                "shippable": false,
                "recurring": false,
                "customerProductAmount": 1,
                "customerTaxAmount": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "iv": "1A0b7S1R"
}
```

But always I am getting "Test Notification Failed to send" message from clickbank.

Is there a sample test response available with anyone who could get a success from test?

Comment: have you solved this? Clickbank send the encrypted values notification and iv. First task is to decrypt this using your secret key then you will get the json values. Just parse the json to get results.

Answer (score 1):

```
string sContent = "";
string encryptednotfication = "";
string vector = "";
using (System.IO.Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
{
     // Move to begining of input stream and read
     receiveStream.Position = 0;
     using (System.IO.StreamReader readStream =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                // Load into XML document
                sContent = readStream.ReadToEnd();
             }
}
```